# Paging issue in MVC3 with JS function calls

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

I have implemented paging in my MVC3 application. Upon clicking each page number a postback occurs and the requested page is shown properly.

Below is my Extension code -

```
public static string PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PageLinks pagelinks, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            int startFrom;
            //Previous Page link
            int divi = (int)pagelinks.Current / pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay;
            if (divi > 0)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl((divi * pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay) - 1));
                tag.InnerHtml = "Prev";
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
            }
            if (divi > 0)
            {
                startFrom = (divi * pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay);
            }
            else
            {
                startFrom = (divi * pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay) + 1;
            }
            int endOn = (startFrom + pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay);
            if (endOn > pagelinks.Total + 1)
                endOn = pagelinks.Total + 1;

            for (int i = startFrom; i < endOn; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagelinks.Current)
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
            }

            if (endOn < pagelinks.Total)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(endOn));
                tag.InnerHtml = "Next";
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Below is source code my View to implement paging -

```
<!-- Paging Strip -->
           <div class="PagerDiv">
                <div class="pagerCurrent">
                <%
                    int? currentPgNo = Model.Pager.Current;
                    int totalItems = Model.Pager.TotalItemCount;
                    int displayRecs = Model.Pager.PageSize;
                %>
                    Showing  <%=(currentPgNo * displayRecs) - (displayRecs - 1)%> - 
                    <%=(currentPgNo * displayRecs < totalItems ? currentPgNo * displayRecs : totalItems)%>
                    out of <%=totalItems%> 
                </div>
                <div class="pager">
                    <%=Html.PageLinks(Model.Pager, x => Url.Action("Index", new { Current = x }))%>
                </div>
                <div class="options">

                    Sort By : <%:Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SortBy, Model.SortOptions, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!-- End Paging-->
```

Below is output - 
[image: Pager]

**The Problem :-**

So far so good. I am facing new difficulty. 
I am having a view with a Div within which data is rendered through json. I am rendering one of my partial view as Json. This partial view shows a list in which paging need to be implemented. I dont want to postback instead new rendered json need to be shown in the Div.

The code

`<%=Html.PageLinks(Model.Pager, x => Url.Action("Index", new { Current = x }))%>`

actually generates the numbered boxes, what i want is to attach a JS function on these numbered boxes instead of a url.

I tried like

`<%=Html.JQueryPageLinks(Model.Pager, x => "MyJSFunction(" + x + ")")%>`

where x represents the page number. Creating another extension but seems no luck.

Here is the code -

```
public static string JQueryPageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PageLinks pagelinks, string jQryFn)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            int startFrom;
            //Previous Page link
            int divi = (int)pagelinks.Current / pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay;
            if (divi > 0)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                //tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl((divi * pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay) - 1));
                tag.Attributes.Add("onclick", jQryFn);
                tag.InnerHtml = "Prev";
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
            }
            if (divi > 0)
            {
                startFrom = (divi * pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay);
            }
            else
            {
                startFrom = (divi * pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay) + 1;
            }
            int endOn = (startFrom + pagelinks.PageLinksToDisplay);
            if (endOn > pagelinks.Total + 1)
                endOn = pagelinks.Total + 1;

            for (int i = startFrom; i < endOn; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                //tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.Attributes.Add("onclick", jQryFn);
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagelinks.Current)
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
            }

            if (endOn < pagelinks.Total)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                //tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(endOn));
                tag.Attributes.Add("onclick", jQryFn);
                tag.InnerHtml = "Next";
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Can someone help me sort this issue.
Thanks for sharing your valuable time and wisdom.

**EDIT:** ***In simplest i want JS function call on page numbers instead of url. 
For ex.

clicking 1 will call MyJSFunction(1), 
clicking 2 will call MyJSFunction(2) 
and so on...***

Answer (score 0):

This is something I wrote (poorly!) a while back which may be of some help. It replaces a specified div with the result of the query

```
        <div id="placeholder">
        <br />Enter your email address below.....<br /><br />
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("VoucherRequest", "Intro", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post" }))    
        {%>
            First Name: <%: Html.TextBox("txtFirstName", "", new { style = "width:50%" })%><br /><br />
            Last Name: <%: Html.TextBox("txtLastName", "", new { style = "width:50%" })%><br /><br />
            Your Email: <%: Html.TextBox("txtEmail", "", new { style = "width:50%" })%><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <br /><br />
            <%: Html.CheckBox("OptIn", false) %> ....
        </div>
```

Comment: it seems you have not understood my requirement. The code you have provided is to submit the form through ajax. Please check the edits to my question.